# TP-LINK WR720N drops connection with uTorrent

Tags: router, utorrent

When I use uTorrent to download and it reaches the highest bandwidth (50 Mbps), it drops the connection for a few minutes, then reconnects. As I often use my Internet connection it is quite annoying when there is suddenly no connection.

The firmware is the latest (07.23), I am connected via Ethernet cable.

I set the QoS to always provide 50 Mbps but with no luck:

[image]

Here is the speed graph:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: I checked the log when a drop occured and found this:  48 INFO 
 INFO 2013-08-17 19:24:06|DHCPC: Network config succeeded.  
 
347 INFO 
 INFO 2013-08-17 19:24:04|DHCP client read, totlen = 368(1048).  
 
346 INFO 
 INFO 2013-08-17 19:24:04|DHCP client tx request.  
 
345 INFO 
 INFO 2013-08-17 19:24:04|DHCP client read, totlen = 368(1048).  
 
344 INFO 
 INFO 2013-08-17 19:24:04|DHCP client tx discover(B).  
 
343 INFO 
 INFO 2013-08-17 19:24:00|DHCPS: 1:0x902b346126e3, 192.168.0.100, ACK in request.

Comment: It dropped the connection 4 times in 20 minutes. What should I set? Why does it drop the connection?

Comment: My connection is 60/6 Mbits/s. When my download speed reaches 1.5 MB/s, I cannot reach the router and speedtest.net shows, I have a 3.5/2 Mbit/s. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it is a common behavior of the routers all around the world. The torrent uses so many connections that the router's routing table is filled with addresses so quickly that it overflows and drops the connection to prevent the incoming of more addresses to route. It should be more fault-tolerant, but when these types of routers were designed, they didn't think of such a scenario.

The only solution is to ***reduce the available connection in your torrent client***.